# VSCode auto compleate when using laravel?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

More specifically when doing this from inside a model.

```
$this->myRelationship->
```

I would expect at this point in typing that I should get a list of all the eloquent collection methods but I do not.

I currently have the PHP Intelephense plugin installed. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Intelephense sees the `myRelationship()` method but doesn't see it as a property because that property is resolved in the `__get` magic method. What you can do is document it above the model like:

```
/**
 * @property \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection $myRelationship
 */
class YourModel extends Model ...
```

and then you will have the autocomplete. Also [this](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/)
It can creates phpDocs automatically like below.

```
php artisan ide-helper:models
```

So your intellisense(for me: [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)) can recognize your model's properties.
See it's Documentation for details